# how I can represent the '?' symbol in a JavaCC grammar?

Tags: javacc

I would like to know how I can represent the '?' symbol in a JavaCC grammar ?
The '?' symbol means that there can be at most one grammar symbol when you use '?' or zero.
For example:

S -> a? B
   B -> b;

So, you can have at most one 'a'. Is not possible more than one a, so you cannot have 'aaaaa';

Thanks;

Answer (score 1):

Use `( ... )?` .  For example

```
void S() : {} { ( <a> )? B() }
void B() : {} { <b> }
```

Comment: For grammar rules, you can also use square brackets, as in `[<a>]`.